# Eofexception in Google app engine / Restlet combination

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet

I created a restful web service using a combination of GAE, objectify for persistence at server side and the restlet framework.

I managed to get everything working: putting new objects, getting, getting the whole list, ... My application works perfectly when I am running it locally in Eclipse using the GAE plugin.

However, after deploying my app to the Google App Engine server, I run into EOFException when getting the data. Here is the client-side code I have:

(servername omitted for safety)

```
ClientResource con = new ClientResource("http://" + servername + "/sidin/event/1003");
con.setRequestEntityBuffering(true); 
eventres = con.wrap(IEventResource.class);
ev = eventres.retrieve();
System.out.println("DONE getting event");
```

This code works fine on the local GAE instance but after deploying this to the server of Google I get the following error:

```
Unable to convert a [application/json,UTF-8] representation into an object of class be.ehb.iwt.sidin.appengine.core.Event

java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2775)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2718)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1909)
at org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonRepresentation.getObject(JacksonRepresentation.java:137)
at org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonConverter.toObject(JacksonConverter.java:218)
at org.restlet.service.ConverterService.toObject(ConverterService.java:167)
at org.restlet.resource.Resource.toObject(Resource.java:828)
at org.restlet.engine.resource.ClientInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInvocationHandler.java:240)
at $Proxy7.retrieve(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:59)
```

Any help or ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Did you try sending the JSON input by hand, using curl or another HTTP client? That will let you know if it is a server or client side issue

Comment: Two items: (1) Did you see anything relevant in the GAE logs?  (2) I have a project with the same configuration (GAE/Objectify/Restlet) and ran into a similar problem in the past that seemed to vanish when I added the following to my createInboundRoot() method: this.getConnectorService().getClientProtocols().add(Protocol.CLAP);  // For GAE?
this.getConnectorService().getClientProtocols().add(Protocol.HTTP);  // For GAE?   this.getConnectorService().getClientProtocols().add(Protocol.HTTPS);  // For GAE? Don't recall the details, so can't guarantee this will fix it.